# java nio Files.write() method not working

Tags: java, parameter-passing

Okay, so I'm trying to use the new Files.write method in Java. [Here is a link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

It says the StandardOpenOption is optional, but everytime I leave it blank, and even when I do put something in there I get a compiler error. For Example...

```
try{
 Files.write("example.txt",byte[] byteArray);
 }
  catch(Exception e){}
```

will result in The method write(Path, byte[], OpenOption...) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path, String)

Comment: What is `byte[] byteArray` as an argument? What do you think that does?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with NIO and everything to do with language syntax. You have:

```
Files.write("example.txt",byte[] byteArray);
```

I don't know what your intention is with that, but you can't declare a variable in a function parameter list like that. You probably mean something like:

```
byte[] byteArray = ...; // populate with data to write.
Files.write("example.txt", byteArray);
```

For a more formal view, dig around through the JLS, starting at [JLS 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). There is ultimately no `ArgumentList` pattern in the language that can accept a `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`.

Comment: i am trying to use `Files.write(path, str.getBytes(charset))` but even though third parameter is optional, it says `The method write(Path, byte[], OpenOption[]) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path, byte[])`

Answer (score 3):

If i change it to

```
try{
    Files.write("example.txt", new byte[0]);
 } catch(Exception e){}
```

i see

> no suitable method found for write(String,byte[])
>   Files.write("example.txt", new byte[0]); 
>   ^ method Files.write(Path,Iterable,Charset,OpenOption...) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to Path by method invocation
>   conversion)
>   method Files.write(Path,byte[],OpenOption...) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to Path by method invocation conversion) 
>   1 error

And if i change to

```
 Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log");
 try{
     byte[] byteArray = ...; // populate with data to write.
     Files.write(path, byteArray);
 } catch(Exception e){}
```

Then i have no compiler warnings.

So, you need:

1. Change String parameter to Path parameter
2. Use byte array variable "byteArray" instead of "byte[] byteArray" because the latter one is an input parameter signature.

Comment: I'd just like to note that you could create a `Path` given a `File` by  invoking `File#toPath()` on your `File` object.

Comment: ah yes, I am being a dumbass. Thank you for clearing that up for me