# Is java.nio.file.Files.write(...) safe?

Tags: java, nio, autocloseable

`java.nio.file.Files.write(...)` method throws IOException

and I can't use it in

```
try(java.nio.file.Files.write(...))
```

construction.

Is it "AutoCloseable" and safe in case of exception?

Comment: The usage of try-with-resource here is incorrect. .write() does not instantiate any resource.

Comment: [java nio Files.write() method not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011101/java-nio-files-write-method-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use try-with-resources, you always need to declare and initialize a variable of a type which implements `AutoCloseable`:

```
try (SomeType someType = someMethodCall()) {
}
```

even if you don't need to refer to `someType` in the body of the block. You can't simply use

```
try (someMethodCall()) {
}
```

In your specific case, `SomeType` would be [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), which doesn't implement `AutoCloseable`, so you can't use it in a try-with-resources statement anyway.

Answer (score 2):

try-with-resources is to be used with resources , but here `try(java.nio.file.Files.write(...))` ,you are just performing a write operation not instantiating any resource.